# makefile dependency doesn't trigger rebuild

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I'm want to have .h files to be included as my dependencies for a given .o file.  I followed [these instructions](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) and adapted them to my Makefile. However when I do `touch myhfile.h` a corresponding .o file is not rebuilt. It seems to me dependencies are correct and are included into the Makefile. Just can't figure out why it is not working. Any help is appreciated. Makefile is included below

```
ROOT=.

BUILDDIR=$(ROOT)/build
LIBDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/lib
OBJDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/obj
INCLUDEDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/include
DEPDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/dep
LIB=mylib
XCOMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
CC=$(XCOMPILE)gcc
AR=$(XCOMPILE)ar

DEPFLAGS+=\
          -MT $@ \
          -MMD \
          -MP \
          -MF \
          $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

CFLAGS+=\
        -Wall \
        -Wextra \
        -Werror \
        -pedantic \
        -std=gnu11 \
        -fPIC

CPPFLAGS+=\
          $(INCLUDE)


SRCDIRS+=\
     $(ROOT)/../3rdparty/log/src \
     $(ROOT)/LTC2947/src \
     $(ROOT)/i2c/src \
     $(ROOT)/spi/src \
     $(ROOT)/sensors/src \
     $(ROOT)/telegraf/src \
     $(ROOT)/uart-packet/src \
     $(ROOT)/STCN75/src \
     $(ROOT)/utils/src

DEPDIRS+=\
         $(SRCDIRS) \
         $(ROOT)/addresses-ports/src

VPATH+=\
       $(SRCDIRS)

SRC+=$(shell find $(SRCDIRS) -type f -name "*\.c")
DEP+=$(shell find $(DEPDIRS) -type f -name "*\.h")

OBJ=$(patsubst %.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(notdir $(SRC)))
INCLUDE=$(addprefix -I,$(sort $(dir $(DEP))))

POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

release: CFLAGS+=-O3
release: all

debug: CFLAGS+=-ggdb
debug: CPPFLAGS+=-DDEBUG
debug: all

all: lib include

lib: $(LIBDIR)/$(LIB).a $(LIBDIR)/$(LIB).so

include: $(INCLUDEDIR)

$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB).a: $(OBJ) | $(LIBDIR)
    $(AR) rcs $@ $^

$(LIBDIR)/$(LIB).so: $(OBJ) | $(LIBDIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -shared $(LDFLAGS) -lc $^ -o $@

$(INCLUDEDIR): $(DEP)
    if [[ ! -d $@ ]]; then mkdir -p $@; fi
    cp $^ $@
    touch $@

%.o: %.c
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(LIBDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRC))))
```

**EDIT**

`$(info $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRC)))))` produced an empty string. `$(info $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRC))))` produced a right list of dependencies

```
./build/dep/./../3rdparty/log/src/log.d ./build/dep/./uart-packet/src/uart_packet.d ./build/dep/./utils/src/utils.d ./build/dep/./telegraf/src/telegraf.d ./build/dep/./i2c/src/myproject_i2c.d ./build/dep/./spi/src/myproject_spi.d ./build/dep/./LTC2947/src/LTC2947.d ./build/dep/./sensors/src/sensors.d ./build/dep/./STCN75/src/STCN75.d
```

So I removed `$(wildcard ...) function`

However that didn't solve the problem.

To test the it I decided to run:

```
1. make clean
2. make 
3. touch telegraf/src/telegraf.h
4. make build/obj/telegraf.d
5. make build/obj/telegraf.Td
6. make build/obj/telegraf.o
```

Steps 1-3 worked fine. However steps 4-6 didn't work.

Step 4 produced a following result:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'buid/dep/telegraf.d'.  Stop.
```

Step 5 produced a following result:
    make: *** No rule to make target 'buid/dep/telegraf.Td'.  Stop.

Step 6 simply didn't rebuild the target.

I took a look at build/dep/telegraf.d after step 2 and here is what I have there:

```
$ cat build/dep/telegraf.d
build/obj/telegraf.o: telegraf/src/telegraf.c ../3rdparty/log/src/log.h \
 telegraf/src/telegraf.h utils/src/utils.h

../3rdparty/log/src/log.h:

telegraf/src/telegraf.h:

utils/src/utils.h:
```

It seems to me dependencies are generated correctly.

I also tried running `make -d build/obj/telegraf.o`. Unfortunately I can't post a whole output for it (stackoverflow won't allow it, message becomes to large). But here is the end of the output. (For those who are interested, full output can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/fUn8bKVR))

```
  No need to remake target 'telegraf.c'; using VPATH name './telegraf/src/telegraf.c'.
  Considering target file 'build/dep/telegraf.d'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'build/dep/telegraf.d'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'telegraf'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'build/dep/telegraf.d'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/dep/telegraf.d'.
  No need to remake target 'build/dep/telegraf.d'.
  Considering target file 'build/dep'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/dep'.
  No need to remake target 'build/dep'.
  Considering target file 'build/obj'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/obj'.
  No need to remake target 'build/obj'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
 Prerequisite './telegraf/src/telegraf.c' is older than target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
 Prerequisite 'build/dep/telegraf.d' is older than target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
 Prerequisite 'build/dep' is order-only for target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
 Prerequisite 'build/obj' is order-only for target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
No need to remake target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.
make: 'build/obj/telegraf.o' is up to date.
```

It looks to that this line is the issue, `Prerequisite 'build/dep/telegraf.d' is older than target 'build/obj/telegraf.o'.`. Somehow I need to make it younger but I'm not sure how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it build the corresponding `.d` file? (Actual names would be helpful.)

Comment: If you add a `$(info $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRC)))))` into your makefile, does it show you all the `.d` files?  If you look at the contents of the `build/dep/myfile.d` file do you see the correct prerequisites listed?  If you run `make -d build/obj/myfile.o` do you see it looking at your header files?  Just based on this makefile it's hard to know what the problem is: you need to debug it.  Since you don't get an error from make, it's probably either not finding your `.d` file at all, or the content of the `.d` file is not correct.

Comment: @MadScientist I've added extra information. I think the bug is in regenerating .d file after .h file has been changed/touched.

Comment: @Beta Yes, it does build a corresponding .d file. I've added extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you've gone running off in the wrong direction here :).

You should not have removed the `$(wildcard ...)`; that is needed/wanted.

The fact that it returned the empty string is *THE* problem you're having and rather than just remove it you needed to figure out why and fix it.  The fact that your `.d` files look like `./build/dep/./../3rdparty/log/src/log.d` is the problem... that is NOT the path to the `.d` files you are creating.  You are creating files like `./build/dep/log.d`

The problem is this: you are creating `.d` files in the recipe using this rule:

```
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@
```

Here, `$*` is the stem of the file so for `./build/obj/log.o` the value of `$*` will be `log`.  So you are creating `./build/dep/log.d`.

But when you convert your `SRC` variable to `.d` files in the include line, you use the `basename` function.  This merely strips off the suffix of the path, it doesn't remove the directory.  So if your source file is `./../3rdparty/log/src/log.c` then `basename` yields `./../3rdparty/log/src/log` and your wildcard matches the wrong thing.

You need to compute your wildcard for your include line like this:

```
include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))
```

Adding the `notdir` to strip out the paths, as well, will give you the dependency file you want: `./build/dep/log.d` etc.